# Gson fromJson returning null object

Tags: java, json, gson

I am frustrated with a silly error, I am trying to parse a json to my desired class but somehow it is returning a null object. My json is as follows:

```
{
  "service_requests": [
    {
      "serviceRequestItems": [
        {
          "entityId": "688210985",
          "entityType": "wh_inventory",
          "sourceArea": "transient",
          "destinationArea": "store",
          "srItemLabels": [
            
          ],
          "attributes": [
            {
              "name": "wid",
              "value": "test"
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

This is being returned from an API call and I have validated this from the debug mode of my IDE.
Following are my classes

```
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
public class PayloadDTO {

    @JsonProperty("service_requests")
    List<SRCreationRequest> serviceRequests;

    public List<SRCreationRequest> getServiceRequests() {
        return serviceRequests;
    }

    public void setServiceRequests(List<SRCreationRequest> serviceRequests) {
        this.serviceRequests = serviceRequests;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {

        return "PayloadDTO{" + "service_requests=" + serviceRequests + '}';
    }
}
public class SRCreationRequest {

    private List<SRItemCreationRequest> serviceRequestItems;

    public List<SRItemCreationRequest> getServiceRequestItems() {

        return serviceRequestItems;
    }

    public void setServiceRequestItems(List<SRItemCreationRequest> serviceRequestItems) {

        this.serviceRequestItems = serviceRequestItems;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {

        return "SRCreationRequest{" + "serviceRequestItems=" + serviceRequestItems + ", tenantId='" + tenantId + '\''
                + ", clientId='" + clientId + '\'' + ", facilityId='" + facilityId + '\'' + ", context='" + context + '\''
                + ", idempotenceKey='" + idempotenceKey + '\'' + ", shardInfo=" + shardInfo + ", apiContext='" + apiContext
                + '\'' + '}';
    }
}
public class SRItemCreationRequest {

    private String entityId;
    private String entityType;
    private SRItemContainer sourceContainer;
    private String sourceArea;
    private SRItemContainer destinationContainer;
    private String destinationArea;
    private List<SRItemLabel> srItemLabels;
    private String groupId;
    private List<SRItemAttribute> attributes;

    public String getEntityId() {

        return entityId;
    }

    public void setEntityId(String entityId) {

        this.entityId = entityId;
    }

    public String getEntityType() {

        return entityType;
    }

    public void setEntityType(String entityType) {

        this.entityType = entityType;
    }

    public SRItemContainer getSourceContainer() {

        return sourceContainer;
    }

    public void setSourceContainer(SRItemContainer sourceContainer) {

        this.sourceContainer = sourceContainer;
    }

    public String getSourceArea() {

        return sourceArea;
    }

    public void setSourceArea(String sourceArea) {

        this.sourceArea = sourceArea;
    }

    public SRItemContainer getDestinationContainer() {

        return destinationContainer;
    }

    public void setDestinationContainer(SRItemContainer destinationContainer) {

        this.destinationContainer = destinationContainer;
    }

    public String getDestinationArea() {

        return destinationArea;
    }

    public void setDestinationArea(String destinationArea) {

        this.destinationArea = destinationArea;
    }

    public List<SRItemLabel> getSrItemLabels() {

        return srItemLabels;
    }

    public void setSrItemLabels(List<SRItemLabel> srItemLabels) {

        this.srItemLabels = srItemLabels;
    }

    public String getGroupId() {

        return groupId;
    }

    public void setGroupId(String groupId) {

        this.groupId = groupId;
    }

    public List<SRItemAttribute> getAttributes() {

        return attributes;
    }

    public void setAttributes(List<SRItemAttribute> attributes) {

        this.attributes = attributes;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {

        return "SRItemCreationRequest{" + "entityId='" + entityId + '\'' + ", entityType='" + entityType + '\''
                + ", sourceContainer=" + sourceContainer + ", sourceArea='" + sourceArea + '\'' + ", destinationContainer="
                + destinationContainer + ", destinationArea='" + destinationArea + '\'' + ", srItemLabels=" + srItemLabels
                + ", groupId='" + groupId + '\'' + ", attributes=" + attributes + '}';
    }
}
```

Both SRItemAttribute and SRItemLabel look like this

```
@ApiModel
public class SRItemAttribute {
    @ApiModelProperty(name = "name", value = "Attribute name")
    @JsonProperty(value = "name")
    @NotEmpty(message = "{sr.attr.name.notnull}")
    private String name;

    @ApiModelProperty(name = "value", value = "Attribute value")
    @JsonProperty(value = "value")
    @NotEmpty(message = "{sr.attr.value.notnull}")
    private String value;

    public SRItemAttribute() {

    }

    public SRItemAttribute(String name, String value) {

        this.name = name;
        this.value = value;
    }

    public String getName() {

        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {

        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getValue() {

        return value;
    }

    public void setValue(String value) {

        this.value = value;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {

        return "SRAttribute{" + "name='" + name + '\'' + ", value='" + value + '\'' + '}';
    }
}
```

and since I'm not using the SRItemContainer and ignoring unknown properties, I'm assuming that should not be a problem.
and I'm parsing as follows

```
Gson gson = new Gson();
        String jsonInString = gson.toJson(//getting from API here);
        LOGGER.debug("jsonInString "+jsonInString); //as above
        PayloadDTO serviceRequests = gson.fromJson(jsonInString, PayloadDTO.class);
```

Can anyone see where I'm going wrong?

Comment: Try implemented the Serializable class in PayloadDTO

Comment: @Beshambher Chaukhwan I didn't get that, could you elaborate?

Comment: To convert to and from json and Java class, the class must implement the Serializable interface so that it can convert it to byte stream. For more detailed information check this link  https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/serialization-in-java/

Comment: The recommendations above regarding `Serializable` are just wrong. Your DTOs are annotated for use with Jackson, whilst your're using Gson. Why are you using different libraries and didn't you suspect something wrong importing classes from totally different packages? Of course you're getting `null`: Gson cannot map JSON `service_requests` to `serviceRequests` because it's accomplished using `@SerializedName` in Gson. Or use Jackson `ObjectMapper`.

Comment: @fluffy is right, I was using the classes from the wrong package. (I was using ObjectMapper library earlier) and Gson was not able to map `serviceRequests` to `service_requests`. Naming the attribute to `service_requests` fixed the issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you checked your second class called `SRCreationRequest`. Doesn't it not require to have annotation as well? for this part:
`private List<SRItemCreationRequest> serviceRequestItems;`

I am thinking you need to add annotation for GSON to read it as an attribute of the API response model. Something like this on the attribute `@JsonProperty("serviceRequestItems")`

For such kind of model generation I always use online tools. doing it manually causes a mistake somewhere and its hard to get for a complex model.

here check this site: http://www.jsonschema2pojo.org/

I have generated your json response to a java class pojo class.

Here is the result:

for PayloadDTO :

```java
public class PayloadDTO {

    @SerializedName("service_requests")
    @Expose
    private List<ServiceRequest> serviceRequests = null;

    public List<ServiceRequest> getServiceRequests() {
        return serviceRequests;
    }

    public void setServiceRequests(List<ServiceRequest> serviceRequests) {
        this.serviceRequests = serviceRequests;
    }

}
```

for ServiceRequest :

```java
public class ServiceRequest {

    @SerializedName("serviceRequestItems")
    @Expose
    private List<ServiceRequestItem> serviceRequestItems = null;

    public List<ServiceRequestItem> getServiceRequestItems() {
        return serviceRequestItems;
    }

    public void setServiceRequestItems(List<ServiceRequestItem> serviceRequestItems) {
        this.serviceRequestItems = serviceRequestItems;
    }

}
```

for ServiceRequestItem:

```java
public class ServiceRequestItem {

    @SerializedName("entityId")
    @Expose
    private String entityId;
    @SerializedName("entityType")
    @Expose
    private String entityType;
    @SerializedName("sourceArea")
    @Expose
    private String sourceArea;
    @SerializedName("destinationArea")
    @Expose
    private String destinationArea;
    @SerializedName("srItemLabels")
    @Expose
    private List<Object> srItemLabels = null;
    @SerializedName("attributes")
    @Expose
    private List<Attribute> attributes = null;

    public String getEntityId() {
        return entityId;
    }

    public void setEntityId(String entityId) {
        this.entityId = entityId;
    }

    public String getEntityType() {
        return entityType;
    }

    public void setEntityType(String entityType) {
        this.entityType = entityType;
    }

    public String getSourceArea() {
        return sourceArea;
    }

    public void setSourceArea(String sourceArea) {
        this.sourceArea = sourceArea;
    }

    public String getDestinationArea() {
        return destinationArea;
    }

    public void setDestinationArea(String destinationArea) {
        this.destinationArea = destinationArea;
    }

    public List<Object> getSrItemLabels() {
        return srItemLabels;
    }

    public void setSrItemLabels(List<Object> srItemLabels) {
        this.srItemLabels = srItemLabels;
    }

    public List<Attribute> getAttributes() {
        return attributes;
    }

    public void setAttributes(List<Attribute> attributes) {
        this.attributes = attributes;
    }

}
```

and lastly for the attribute models:

```java
public class Attribute {

    @SerializedName("name")
    @Expose
    private String name;
    @SerializedName("value")
    @Expose
    private String value;

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getValue() {
        return value;
    }

    public void setValue(String value) {
        this.value = value;
    }

}
```

The annotations I used might be a little different from that you used but it will generate the correct according to your setting on the right side options.

Here is my config for your model in site:

[image]

Comment: This is along the direction of what I should have done and thank you for pointing me to the right resource for the future.